# How Do I Get All Records From A DNS Server?

Tags: dns

How do I get all records from a DNS server? For example, I want to host a local DNS server so that I would get faster DNS access (I know about the huge size). How do I download the hosts file from a DNS server?

Comment: Most DNS servers don't use hosts files for configuration (only some very basic ones used for simple LANs do).

Comment: It's not really clear what you are asking. Are you trying to download the DNS records for the entire Internet? They *change* from moment to moment so this would be completely impractical even if it were possible.

Comment: Would it be possible to get them at a specific timeframe?

Comment: 1) it is not possible and 2) if it was possible that would certainly not be a solution to "so that I would get faster DNS access (I know about the huge size)" which is not even clear. Please have a look first at some introductory level documents on the DNS and how it works and then come back for specific question, but not on this site as your questions at this stage are not related to programming. Try [su] for example, after having read the help section.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Would you mind moving it there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get the DNS records for the entire Internet. It is a decentralised system.

You have to ask for a specific address, and then the DNS server will either return it because it is the master server for it, return it because it has it cached as the TTL hasn't expired, or go and ask another server for it.

There's no way to ask a server to give you everything it has, let alone every server everywhere.

Comment: So then how are new DNS servers created? Also, since it's a decentralized system everyone should be able to have access to information, this way no one could change it, like bitcoin, right? How do I gain access to the DNS records through being an aspiring DNS server?

Comment: You pick some DNS server software and then point it at an upstream DNS server.

Answer (score 0):

If DNS server doesn't have answer ready for you he will ask next server etc..

You don't need your local DNS server unless you want to have internal resolver for some internal services you are hosting. It's easier to use some of public DNS servers for domain's you own.

Also 2 lets say most famous software for DNS resolving like Bind and PowerDNS uses config files and database to keep records not hosts files.

Best regards.

Comment: "If DNS server doesn't have answer ready for you he will ask next server etc.." The DNS does not work like that. If you ask an authoritative resolver you have an answer or a NXDOMAIN or a refusal to reply, to summarize. In all those cases you do not ask the next server. If asking a recursive nameserver you have a reply, positive or negative. If negative, you do not go to another resolver. You do that only if the first one did not reply at all (a negative reply is different from no reply)

Comment: "You don't need your local DNS server" You sure can want to install a local recursive nameserver that can give you some benefits like local DNSSEC validation, control of the cache, use of DOH/DOT protocols as you like, and faster resolutions.

Comment: "Also 2 lets say most famous software for DNS resolving like Bind and PowerDNS uses config files and database to keep records not hosts files." They use zonefiles which are text files, formatted in a specific way. Among other solutions. But historically that was the only solution.